# Removing Info Before Filename.exe

Tags: c#, listbox, directory, streamreader

This lists all files in all directory's from the directory i choose with folderBrowserDialog1, but when it loads them into the listBox it comes up with the item in the listBox like this

C:\users\username\desktop\filename.exe

C:\users\username\desktop\filename.exe

C:\users\username\desktop\filename.exe

and so on.. is there any way to remove C:\users\username\desktop\ and just keep filename.exe

Here's my code it may help.

```
private void DirSearch(string dir)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment to @Dennis, this should work.

```
private void DirSearch(string dir)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(file.Replace(dir, string.empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what i wanted but didnt clarify it right thanks David.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method:

```
 ListBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Comment: Thanks that helped for something else but i only wanted to remove just the C:\users\username\desktop\ not the rest like say there was a file in C:\users\username\desktop\folder\folder\filename.exe, i want to keep the folder\folder\filename part.

Comment: @Terrii: this removes exactly "C:\users\username\desktop\" (path) from "C:\users\username\desktop\filename.exe" and returns "filename.exe" (file name). This what is your question about, isn't it? If it is not, please, clarify it.

Comment: Davids comment does what i wanted it to do sorry i didnt clarify it right

Answer (score 1):

try recursive method

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        DirSearch(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    }
    private void DirSearch(string dir)
    {
        try
        {
            string userpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (!dir.Equals(userpath))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                IEnumerable<string> dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir);
                foreach (string dsdir in dirs)
                {
                    DirSearch(dsdir);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Davids comment does everything this does and its smaller and more code saving. thanks for your contribution anyway.